# Where is Gwendolyn?

Tags: glitch-2011

I am trying to get some Random Kindness, but to do that I need a Quest from Gwendolyn. However, I do not know where to find her.

I know it is somewhere near Jethimadh Tower...but where exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to complete the Jethimadh Tower quest. To start it:

> You need to first move through a series of locked doors and rooms inside Jethimadh Tower. You will need to enter from either the North or South Street entrance. The first key should be given to you automatically when you enter the tower for the first time. The next key can be found in one of the Secrets of Jethimadh Tower locations. **The most difficult part of the quest is actually finding the keys here. They respawn slowly, and if there is a large number of other players around you might not be able to find one**.
>  After that you will move through a series of rooms, using keys obtained in the previous room to open the door to the next. Spinach will be required. They can be harvested (so bring a hoe) from the first locked room in the tower. The *quest* for Gwendolyn will start at the point when you find a Greeterbot.

[A more detailed explanation (spoilers)](http://www.glitch-strategy.com/wiki/Jethimadh_Tower:_Base) can be found on the Wiki. As for the quest itself,

> You'll move through a series of weird (by Glitch standards!) sceneries. This stage is actually pretty easy, as everything is very linear. You will need to do a fair bit of platforming. At the end you'll meet Gwendolyn, and she will give you a Random Kindness, in addition to the usual quest rewards. The quest can be repeated for 100 currents by going back to the Greeterbot.

There is also a more mundane method for obtaining Random Kindness - by harvesting crops with Croppery II skill. If you need one (or a key) I can send it to you if you drop your username in a comment.